# Expecting string but getting nil in Rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am working on a Ruby problem called "Speaking Grandma" where I need to create a method that should should take in a string argument containing a phrase and check to see if the phrase is written in all uppercase: if it isn't, then grandma can't hear you. She should then respond with (return) HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!.

However, if you shout at her (i.e. call the method with a string argument containing a phrase that is all uppercase, then she can hear you (or at least she thinks that she can) and should respond with (return) NO, NOT SINCE 1938!.

I wrote the following code:

```
def speak_to_grandma(input)
if
  input != input.upcase
  puts 'HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!' 
else
  puts 'NO, NOT SINCE 1938!'
end
end
```

When I run RSpec, I fail both tests. It gives the following message:

```
Failure/Error: expect(speak_to_grandma('Hi Nana, how are you?')).to eq 'HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!'
       expected: "HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!"
            got: nil
```

and

```
 Failure/Error: expect(speak_to_grandma('WHAT DID YOU EAT TODAY?')).to eq "NO,          NOT SINCE 1938!"
       expected: "NO, NOT SINCE 1938!"
            got: nil
       (compared using ==)
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong here. Can anyone help?

Comment: `speak_to_grandma` isn't returning the expected string, it's printing it.  `eq` from RSpec is checking the return value which is going to be nil (because that's what `puts` returns).  Take a look at [this documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers#output-instance_method) which can be used to check against expected output.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Just needed that little guidance from you and I have figured it out! Awesome!

Answer (score 3):

The `speak_to_grandma` method returns the return value of the `puts` method, being the last line in the method. The return value of `puts` is `nil`([Why are all my puts returning =>nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741329/why-are-all-my-puts-returning-nil_))

The `eq` method in Rspec checks the return value of a method. The string is output to the screen with `puts`, but the return value is `nil`, and that's what Rspec is checking for.

If you remove `puts`, the tests should pass, because the string will be the return value of the method. But the correct way would be to test it with the `output` method in Rspec. Write your test like this:

```
expect { speak_to_grandma('WHAT DID YOU EAT TODAY?') }.to output("NO, NOT SINCE 1938!").to_stdout
```